# Django rest framework browsable api is rendering both a PUT and a POST form when it should only be rendering a POST form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]

Normally when I navigate to the url http://localhost:8000/api/v1/public_profiles/ using a ModelViewSet, I only get a POST form and when I navigate to a specific resource such as http://localhost:8000/api/v1/public_profiles/123456/ I only get a PUT/PATCH form.  **Currently both forms are being rendered at both locations.**

For many of my routes I will need more control over my views so I dropped down to generic views.  I also wanted to take advantage of the router so I mixed in a generic viewset.  The image above is the result of implementing the following view:

```
class PublicProfileViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, generics.ListCreateAPIView, generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = PublicProfile.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return PublicProfileReadSerializer
        elif self.action == 'retrieve':
            return PublicProfileReadSerializer
        elif self.action == 'create':
            return PublicProfileCreateSerializer
        elif self.action == 'update':
            return PublicProfileUpdateSerializer
        else:
            return PublicProfileReadSerializer
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this so that a POST form renders on the LIST action and PUT/PATCH form renders on the RETRIEVE action?

One thing I have tried is to use a ViewSet but then I don't get any forms generated because there is no 'serializer_class':

```
class PublicProfileViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

     def list(self, request):
         queryset = PublicProfile.objects.all()
         serializer = PublicProfileReadSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
         return Response(serializer.data)

     def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
         queryset = PublicProfile.objects.all()
         public_profile = get_object_or_404(PublicProfile, pk=pk)
         serializer = PublicProfileReadSerializer(public_profile, context={'request': request})
         return Response(serializer.data)

     def create(self, request):
         serializer = PublicProfileCreateSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
         if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data)

     def update(self, request, pk=None):
         instance = get_object_or_404(PublicProfile, pk=pk)
         serializer = PublicProfileUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
         if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data)

     def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
         instance = get_object_or_404(PublicProfile, pk=pk)
         serializer = PublicProfileUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data, context={'request': request}, partial=True)
         if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data)

     def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
         instance = get_object_or_404(PublicProfile, pk=pk)
         instance.user.is_active = False
         instance.user.save()
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Why you don't separate the view to 2 views. one for `ListCreate` and the other for `RetrieveUpdate`

Comment: @PeterSobhi How would that affect my router?

Answer (score 1):

Those forms are propagating from Django Rest Framework's default non-JSON Browsable API as JSON-API only specifies a JSON media type. But it might be a worthwhile thing to make a browsable JSON-API interface, although I personally prefer using Postman.

Take a look in settings for the parser and renderer classes:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    # 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        # application/vnd.api+json
        'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        # text/html: ?format=api
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework_json_api.metadata.JSONAPIMetadata',
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'vnd.api+json',
    'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.MultiPartRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer'
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first you are logged in . That was my issue.

[image] When you are logged from the {{url}}/admin

[image]
When i am logged in